# Getting the value of sibling nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the following XML

```
<CN>12<CN>
<CT>XYXY</CT>
```

I need the result AS

```
<DIV>12  XYXY</DIV>
```

I'm USING the floowing XSLT but it's not working

```
<xsl:variable name="x"><xsl:value-of  select="CN"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="CT">
 <div class="chap-title"><span><xsl:value-of select="$x"/></span></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
<input>
    <CN>12</CN>
    <CT>XYXY</CT>
</input>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"
                method="xml"
                encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/input">
        <DIV>
            <xsl:value-of select="CN"/>
            <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CT"/>
        </DIV>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```